# Eloquent relationship depth

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

In my app I have multiple relations. User has many events. Many events has many participants.

For example Events model:

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Participant');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I want to get all user events participants and paginate them.

`$participants = $user->events->participants;` 
This clearly does not work thats why I am trying something like this

```
$events = $user->events;
$participants = [];
foreach ($events as $event) {
   $participants[] = $event->participants;
}
return $participants;
```

This works in terms of getting the data array, but I cannot paginate it using DB pagination, because it is an array.

Is there another way of gathering all the participants in deeper relations? Or how else I can use laravel or lumen pagination?

Edit: Adding migrations

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...  
});
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
});
Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...   
});
Schema::create('event_participant', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('event_id');
    $table->integer('participant_id');
});
```

EDIT 2: My Solution:
Made participants array Laravel Collection and added macro method for pagination as answered here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-laravel-collection

Comment: Do you want to paginate the participants?

Comment: @HaiderAli yes but from the users events only.

Comment: Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Participant', 'App\Event');` this does not really work since I have pivot table between Participants and Events. How can I make it refer to pivot table instead of searching event_id in Participants table?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want general access to the paginator, this is what I use.  Maybe it will be helpful sometime.

```
/**
 * @param $array
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
public static function makePaginatorForArray(array $array){
    $collection = collect($array);

    return self::makePaginatorForCollection($collection);
}

/**
 * This should match laravel's built in Model::paginate()
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Support\Collection $collection
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
public static function makePaginatorForCollection(\Illuminate\Support\Collection $collection){
    $current_page = (request()->has('page') ? request()->page : 1) - 1;//off by 1 (make zero start)
    $per_page     = (request()->has('per_page') ? request()->per_page : config('pagination.per_page')) * 1;

    if(env('APP_ENV') == 'testing'){
        $per_page = 0;
    }

    if($per_page){
        $page_data = $collection->slice($current_page * $per_page, $per_page)->all();
    }else{
        $page_data = $collection->all();
        $per_page  = count($page_data) + 1;
    }

    return new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(array_values($page_data), count($collection), $per_page);
}
```

To use this...

```
public function myControllerMethod(Request $request){
  $lots_of_data = MyModel::all()->pluck('deeper_data')->flatten();
  return Helpers::makePaginatorForCollection($lots_of_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HasManyThrough relationship suits the situation best. So in your user model add this method:

```
public function eventsParticipants()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Participant', 'App\Event');
}
```

And then you can get user Event participants using the relationship defined and paginate it as well easily.

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
$user->eventsParticipants->paginate(5);
```

Comment: This does not really work since I have pivot table between Participants and Events. How can I make it refer to pivot table instead of searching event_id in Participants table like this does?

Comment: can you please add your migration or schema to the question so we can see.

Comment: Added migrations

Answer (score 0):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with support for `BelongsToMany`: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function participants() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Participant::class, [Event::class, 'event_participant']);
    }
}

$user->participants()->paginate();
```